# CLT for stochastic process.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are **i.r.v.** with $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = \mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \sigma^2$. Then let $Z(t) = \sup \left\{n : \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i} \le t\right\}$.

And we need to show that $\dfrac{Z(t) - t/\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{t/\mu^3}} \xrightarrow[t \to \infty]{d} N(0,1)$.

Have no hot to step it with stochastic processes. I've thought about prove something like law of large numbers for $Z(t)/t$. I guess it should goes to $\frac{1}{\mu}$. But what else ?

Comment: Are you given that $X_i$ all have the same distribution as well? Are they **i.i.d.**?

Comment: @MikeEarnest yes, it's right